# Is it possible to put namespaces in Visual Studio UML?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, uml

Is it possible? Something like this:
[image]
<sub>(source: [agilemodeling.com](http://www.agilemodeling.com/images/models/packageContents.JPG))</sub>

being it of course, that instead of packages, it'd appear as namespace.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this topic help?

[Defining Packages and Namespaces in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465144.aspx)